# Accepting Values in variables

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I am creating an addon for blender 2.75. Is there a way to accept user's input by creating a Variable? There can be an input slot in the Tools panel, and the user can enter the value in it, which will be stored in a variable which can use later in my code. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a custom permanent property in Blender 2.70 python script to access in GUI Panel](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8367/creating-a-custom-permanent-property-in-blender-2-70-python-script-to-access-in). Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36587/how-to-define-customized-property-in-material